# Black Body problem and chi square minimize error

Tags: python, pandas, minimize, chi-squared

I'm a freshman in python and I'm trying to make a code that calculates the correct temperature for a black body distribution problem.
The body in question is the universe and I'm using the data from the FIRAS CMB Monopole Spectrum [(you can get them here)](https://lambda.gsfc.nasa.gov/product/cobe/firas_monopole_get.cfm).

The problem is that: when I minimize with chi-square-ish the value of chi square always returns the same value every time.

I don't know what or where the problem is and at this point, I'm tired of trying different things.

By the way, I just want to store each value of the chi-square-ish into an array, that's all I need.

```py
import numpy as n
import scipy.constants as scy
import pandas as p 
a=p.read_csv('spec-1-mod.csv') 
b=a.loc[:,"column1"]
nn=a.loc[:,"column2"]
n2n=a.loc[:,"column4"]
def disPlanckTeoric(nu,Tin):
    jj=2*scy.h*scy.c*(nu**3)/scy.c**2
    jk=(scy.h*nu)/scy.k*Tin
    return jj*(1/(n.exp(jk)-1))
T=300
Tsize=n.arange(T,0,-1)
expe=n.array(nn)
otra=n.array(n2n) 
for j in range (len(Tsize)):
    teo=n.array(disPlanckTeoric(b,T)) 
    chi=n.sqrt(sum((((expe-teo))/otra)**2))
    chiM=n.empty((2,len(Tsize)))
    for k in range(len(Tsize)):
        chiM[:,k]=chi
    T=T-0.1
#print(chiM) #Just to see that the values are all the same
```

Answer (score 0):

you have some mistyping in your code. for example Planck distribution there is no `c` in numerator and in `jk=(scy.h*nu)/scy.k*Tin` you should put `scy.k*Tin` in parentheses: `jk=(scy.h*nu)/(scy.k*Tin)`. in your code `chi=n.sqrt(sum((((expe-teo))/otra)**2))` the right part is same number because `sum` is always return one number for every value of `j`.

however I changed your code. I did not use `pandas` and `numpy`. I am not even sure that the curve my code is plotting is what you want. but check it out.

```
from math import *
from scipy.constants import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lines = open('firas_monopole_spec_v1.txt','r').readlines()
lines = [ line for line in lines if line[0] != '#' ] 
column0 = []
column1 = []
column2 = []
column3 = []
column4 = []
for line in lines:
    line_list = [ element for element in line.split(' ') if element != '' ]
    line_list[-1] = line_list[-1][:-1]
    column0.append( line_list[0] )
    column1.append( line_list[1] )
    column2.append( line_list[2] )
    column3.append( line_list[3] )
    column4.append( line_list[4] )

def disPlanckTeoric(nu,Tin):
    jj=2*h*(nu**3)/c**2
    jk=(h*nu)/(k*Tin)
    return jj*(1/(exp(jk)-1))

T=300
b = column0
expe = column1
otra = column3
teo = []
chi = []
tmp = []
T_arr = []
for j in range(0,len(b)):
    T_arr.append(j+1)
    for i in range(len(b)):
        teo.append( disPlanckTeoric(float(b[i]),T_arr[j]) )
        tmp.append( ( ( float(expe[i])-float(teo[i]) ) / float(otra[i]) )**2 )
    chi.append( sqrt( sum( tmp) ) )

plt.plot(chi,T_arr)
plt.show()
```